# Xsd:list--> date issue

Tags: xml, xsd, jaxb

I am using JAXB to parse my xml schema(xsd). I have a complexType as follows:

```
<xsd:complexType name="PromotionalInfo">
    <xsd:attribute name="promotionName" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="blackOutDates" type="DateList"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="amount" type="xsd:float" use="required"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="endDate" type="com:Date"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="startDate" type="com:Date"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="purchaseEndDate" type="com:Date"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="purchaseStartDate" type="com:Date"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="promoType" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="shortMarketingText" type="FiftyLimString" use="required"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="numNightsRequired" type="xsd:int"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="numNightsFree" type="xsd:int"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="termsAndConditions" type="ThousandLimString"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="customerFulfillmentRequirements" type="ThousandLimString"/>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:simpleType name="DateList" id="DateList">
    <xsd:list itemType="com:Date"/>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

Now the problem is, my promotionalInfo class that Jaxb is creating has DateList object of List type instead of List type. Does anyone knows whether it is a bug in JAXB compliler, and if it is, than is there a workaround in my case??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found out by looking at [bindingSchema.xsd](http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd) that for xs:list our type cannot be xsd:date type.